# O que deve-se fazer com perguntas amplas?

Tags: debate

O que deve-se fazer com perguntas amplas que não são do tipo "Faz pra mim"? Hoje na fila de análise vi esta questão: [Como listar e consultar contatos com PHP e Javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67523/listar-contatos-e-ao-clicar-consultar-informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-no-bd-php-mysql) ela estava na lista por ser baseada em opiniões, não estou questionando quem votou até concordo em um amplo demais (até comentei pro user quebrar a pergunta em partes) e votei pra deixar aberta, sei que segundo as politicas do site eu fiz errado porém já estive na mesma situação do autor e é muito ruim não ter um norte para seguir.

Comment: Achei que a questão é sim um do tipo "Faz pra mim", você não achou? Eu, no caso, votei para fechar, e escolhi o motivo de fechamento "Amplo demais", mas poderia ter escolhido como "fora de tópico" também, por causa do tipo "faz para mim". Discordo que seja "Baseado em opiniões". Até agora foram três votos de fechamento por "Amplo demais". Você acha que ela pode ser salva?

Comment: Se ela for quebrada em pequenas partes poderia ser salva (até comentei isso na própria pergunta).